# Basic connection error using Python to connect to TWS

Tags: python, tws

I started coding to help me improve my trading execution process using python and the IBKR software.

I wrote (was helped) a code for a simple connection before attempting to enter the logic behind.

i did go through the posts on stack concerning the same. from ensuring the socket ports are matching to enabling the activex but to no avail.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AToXt.png)

```
from ib_insync import IB

ib = IB()
try:
    ib.connect('127.0.0.1', 7496, clientId=0)
    print("Connection successful")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error connecting to IB: {e}")
```

i have added screenshots 2 and 3 to show the connection and disconnection. it happens within microseconds. i added a timeout of 60 to see if it holds. it does for a minute and then disconnects.

[the disconnection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yUaf.png)